Connecting QGIS/QField to external object storage buckets (Google cloud storage) for sending images directly to the bucket
I am struggling to understand how to authenticate QGIS to connect with Google Cloud storage when configuring the attachment widget.
I have exported a JSON key for a service account, but not sure which authentication type to choose. Is it easier if I use S3?
There used to be an option to connect to S3, but this seems to have been removed in the newer version. Any advice? How can I ultimately connect QGIS to remote storage to post images?
